# The program flow doesn't enter event handler

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I have 2 ASP.NET applications. There's ASCX user control in one of them but it's used in both.

When I run the application where user control is not the program flow enters the event handler. When I run the application where user control is the program flow doesn't enter the event handler.

The code looks as follows:

1) HTML:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CashdeskMenuHolder" Runat="server" Visible="False">
    <table width="99%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
        <tr>
            <td width="65" align="center" class="mainMenu" onmouseover=" this.style.background = '#F5F6AF'; " onmouseout=" this.style.background = '#E8E8E8'; ">
                <site:secureLink runat="server" ID="Exit" Name="выход" CssClass="MainMenu" Allow="wizard,admin,kassaThermo,kassa,kassaPechat,kassaPechatSpec,kassaPechatExt,kassaExpress,kassaManager,placeManager"/>            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

2) Code behind:

```
private void InitEvents()
{
    Exit.LinkClick += Exit_Click;
}

void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["KassaLogOff"] = true;
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: you need to re-initialize your user control - else the events will be lost. Do it in pre-init or Load

Comment: What does it mean re-initialize?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question - i thought u were dynamically adding the user control (in code). Can you share - when is the InitEvents method called? Also can u tell us what is LinkClick

Answer (score 0):

Edit: User controls need to be recreated during each postback - else the events will be lost.

I am not sure where you are calling the `InitEvents` method but this needs to be called during every postback - so setting it OnInit is a good option.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnInit(e); 
     InitEvents();
}
```

Comment: What does it mean re-initialize user control?